# Is it possible to brick a sensor by writing to reserved bits? (ADS1259)

Tags: c, sensors, adc

I am writing a driver for a 24 bit SPI-controlled ADC, which has 9 total accessible registers. 3 config registers, 3 offset calibration registers and 3 gain calibration registers. I am just curious if it's possible to brick these kinds of ICs, by writing to reserved bits or different from default values, or permanently damage it via software (I don't have to deal with electrical/hardware).

I had a bit of a bad experience bricking an NXP chip at work, which I know is very different but want to make sure I don't do it again.

[image: Image of register configurations]

Answer (score 1):

I'd say, it depends. Some chips might get bricked, others don't. Only their creators know for sure, and since they commonly do not disclose such information, we just can try. Which potentially leads to bricked chips.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, absolutely. A reserved bit might simply be an unused dummy bit. Or, maybe it is a bit with a proprietary, undocumented function. It’s fairly common, in my experience, for manufacturers of chips to withhold some functions from the public documentation, either because they reveal inner workings of the chips (i.e. trade secrets) or because they are functions not meant for consumers (e.g. test functions, firmware upgrades).

Once upon a time I worked with a manufacturer of embedded chips. We had some trouble getting a particular rarely-used function to work on our chips. The manufacturer eventually figured out the issue and sent us a patch - a sequence of “magic” writes to certain reserved bits that unlocked a firmware upgrade mode *in production hardware*, combined with some encrypted firmware blob. Sure enough, their patch really did fix the problem, without needing to wait for another respin of the hardware. (It was surprising to me to have a firmware write function on what was a very cheap part, but it seems like it’s cheaper these days to have a basic microcontroller + flash memory SoC on your die than to spin something custom with ROM, I guess).

From this I inferred that writes to reserved bits might really be able to permanently alter the hardware. Writing reserved bits might flip on unwanted/unexpected functions, enable undocumented operating modes, or overwrite device firmware. Unexpected operating modes could damage the chip if the external wiring doesn’t match the mode (e.g. a test mode that shorts certain pins).

In summary: unless you’ve got spare chips to fully test these effects, don’t write reserved bits!